# InvalidResourceType The resource type could not be found in the namespace Azure Python SDK Error

Tags: python, azure, sdk

I'm hitting the following error when trying to run:

`resource_client.resources.get( 'MyResourceGroup', 'Microsoft.Network', '/Resource/Group/Id', 'routeTables', 'Subnet-1-RouteTable', '2015-01-01' )`:

For reference, [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/python/api/azure.mgmt.resource.resources.v2017_05_10.operations.resourcesoperations?view=azure-python) is the function documentation.

Error:

```
Message: The resource type could not be found in the namespace 'Microsoft.Network' for api version '2015-01-01'.
```

I've tried modifying the following without success:

- changing API version to `'v2015-01-01'` (I can't find any examples of anyone calling this Azure Python SDK function to figure out what the format is supposed to be, any pointer to one would be greatly appreciated)
- using `'Microsoft.Network/routeTables'` instead of `'routeTables'`

I can't find a list of API versions, but I have seen `2015-01-01` thrown around so I used that here, but if someone has a list of APIs or one that will work for this resource type that would be great.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is there a specific reason you don't want to use the "azure-mgmt-network" client directly?
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/python/api/azure.mgmt.network.v2017_03_01.operations.routetablesoperations?view=azure-python

This should simplify a lot your situation.

To answer to your specific problem, I think "routeTable" just does not exist in 2015-01-01 (as the message said). This is an old ApiVersion, and that's not even supported in official SDKs. You should try 2017-03-01.

And about the call itself example, this unittest might help you:
https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-python/blob/master/azure-mgmt/tests/test_mgmt_resource.py#L156-L164

But again, I strongly suggest you to just use the Network client and not generic Resource.

(I own the Python SDK at MS)

Comment: Thanks Laurent, using the network client as follows worked for me to grab a route: `network_client.routes.get( 'ResourceGroupName', 'RouteTableName', 'RouteName' )`